# Error: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Error: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':qr_code_scanner' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzCrm.png)